Xero API ODBC driver
I am looking to build a XERO ODBC driver.
Are there any examples of where someone has done it or is willing to provide support ?
Limited technical skills so I thought I would ask if it has been done before.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
